# how can I write these equations in 2 columns

Tags: equations

Since the answers exist , I changed and edited my code to the setting part of it , so I could ask you to please help me , how to edit mine to be able to correctly use your codes, above all , I prefered the first solution of Bernard but I could not use it

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}



\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\newcommand*{\var}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}

\pagestyle{empty}



\begin{document}

    {\footnotesize
\begin{flalign*}
A11 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{∑ SF_{11_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{ϵ_{11}} = \frac{\num{66114.06667654557}}{\num{0.0005242901}} = \SI{126102075.631} {\N\m}
 & D11 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{∑ SM_{1_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{κ_{11}} = \frac{0.106}{0.0002} = \SI{373.068}{\N\m} \\
A12 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{∑ SF_{12_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{ϵ_{12}} = \frac{\num{6295.129}}{\num{0.00011}} = \SI{56957543.627}{\N\m}
 & D12 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{∑ SM_{2_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{κ_{11}} = \frac{0.355}{\num{0.0002}} = \SI{1250.853}{\N\m} \\
 A22 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{∑ SF_{22_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{ϵ_{11}} = \frac{\num{36114775.225}}{0.336} = \SI{107378189.106}{\N\m}
 & D22 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{∑ SM_{2_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{κ_{22}} = \frac{0.733}{0.304} = \SI{2.404}{\N\m} \\
A66 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{∑ SF_{33_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{ϵ_{12}} = \frac{\num{7836440.625}}{0.279} = \SI{28004682.576}{\N\m}
 & D66 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{∑ SM_{3_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{κ_{12}} = \frac{0.389}{0.571} = \SI{1.22}{\N\m}
\end{flalign*}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please produce a more minimal setting part? There are a bunch of packages that are not needed at all by your equations, and there are also external files to be included (`appendiceA`, etc.) that we can't have.

Comment: @fpast sure I did it , is this right ?

Comment: no no , I wanted to know , using the first solution of Bernard , why does it give error ?

Comment: I put it , this one doesn't work

Comment: thank you Dear Mico , the problem of commenting is that I could not manage to edit the code there , despite there is help @Mico

Comment: @Mico I used your solution , but only that I just wanted all the calculations be in one line for each parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a single `align*` environment inside a `multicols` environment.

As the other answers suggest as well, I recommend the `\SI` macro (of the `siunitx` package) to typeset numbers and their associated scientific units. Incidentally, if "SF", "SM", and "Ext" are variable names, they should be rendered in text-italics rather than in math-italics. This can be done by encasing the terms in `\textit` macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align*' environment
  \allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{multicol} % for 'multicols' environment
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page margins here
\usepackage[group-digits=false]{siunitx} % for '\SI' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}%
\begin{align*}
A11= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textit{SF}_{11_{i}}}{\textit{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{11}} 
&= \frac{66114.06667654557}{0.0005242901} \\
&= \SI{126102075.631}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
A12= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textit{SF}_{12_{i}}}{\textit{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{12}} 
&= \frac{6295.129}{0.00011} \\
&= \SI{56957543.627}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
A22= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textit{SF}_{22_{i}}}{\textit{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{11}} 
&= \frac{36114775.225}{0.336} \\
&= \SI{107378189.106}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
A66= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textit{SF}_{33_{i}}}{\textit{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{12}} 
&= \frac{7836440.625}{0.279} \\
&= \SI{28004682.576}{\newton\meter}
\\ {}\\ % extra space at start of second column
D11= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textit{SM}_{1_{i}}}{\textit{Ext}}}{\kappa_{11}} 
&= \frac{0.106}{0.0002} \\
&= \SI{373.068}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex] 
D12= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textit{SM}_{2_{i}}}{\textit{Ext}}}{\kappa_{11}} 
&= \frac{0.355}{0.0002} \\
&= \SI{1250.853}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
D22= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textit{SM}_{2_{i}}}{\textit{Ext}}}{\kappa_{22}} 
&= \frac{0.733}{0.304} \\
&= \SI{2.404}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
D66= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textit{SM}_{3_{i}}}{\textit{Ext}}}{\kappa_{12}} 
&= \frac{0.389}{0.571} \\
&= \SI{1.22}{\newton\meter}
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum**: If using LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX is an option for you, you can set up a little macro that calculates the ratios for you -- no need to do it "by hand". (It turns out that quite a few of the numeric results you provided in your example code are in need of correction.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align*' environment
  \allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{multicol} % for 'multicols' environment
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page margins here
\usepackage[group-digits=false]{siunitx} % for '\SI' macro

\usepackage{luacode}  % for 'luacode' environment
%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}  
function formatted_division ( n, d )
    tex.sprint( string.format( "%.3f", n/d ) ) 
end 
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code: macro '\mycalc' takes two arguments
\newcommand\mycalc[2]{\directlua{ 
    formatted_division(#1,#2) } }

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{align*} 
A11= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textrm{SF}_{11_{i}}}{\textrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{11}} 
&= \frac{66114.06667654557}{0.0005242901} \\
&= \SI{\mycalc{66114.06667654557}{0.0005242901}}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
A12= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textrm{SF}_{12_{i}}}{\textrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{12}} 
&= \frac{6295.129}{0.00011} \\
&= \SI{\mycalc{6295.129}{0.00011}}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
A22= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textrm{SF}_{22_{i}}}{\textrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{11}} 
&= \frac{36114775.225}{0.336} \\
&= \SI{\mycalc{36114775.225}{0.336}}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
A66= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textrm{SF}_{33_{i}}}{\textrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{12}} 
&= \frac{7836440.625}{0.279} \\
&= \SI{\mycalc{7836440.625}{0.279}}{\newton\meter}
\\ {}\\ % extra space at start of second column
D11= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textrm{SM}_{1_{i}}}{\textrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{11}} 
&= \frac{0.106}{0.0002} \\
&= \SI{\mycalc{0.106}{0.0002}}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex] 
D12= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textrm{SM}_{2_{i}}}{\textrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{11}} 
&= \frac{0.355}{0.0002} \\
&= \SI{\mycalc{0.355}{0.0002}}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
D22= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textrm{SM}_{2_{i}}}{\textrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{22}} 
&= \frac{0.733}{0.304} \\
&= \SI{\mycalc{0.733}{0.304}}{\newton\meter}
\\[2ex]
D66= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum \textrm{SM}_{3_{i}}}{\textrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{12}} 
&= \frac{0.389}{0.571} \\
&= \SI{\mycalc{0.389}{0.571}}{\newton\meter}
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked but didnt create 2 collumns

Comment: @Farzad64 - Did you load the `multicol` package and provide the instructions `\begin{multicols}{2}` and `\end{multicols}` before and after the `align*` environment? Without these instructions, two-column mode won't occur.

Comment: yes dear @mico I did copy that all also put the multicul package up there , but didnt work

Comment: @Farzad64 - What does "doesn't work" mean? An error message, a warning message, or something else? The proposed solution clearly "worked", as the screenshop I posted demonstrates. If it doesn't work for you, something in your code has to be significantly different from the solution I suggested. I'm curious to learn what that "something" may be.

Answer (score 5):

Your equations are too long for a line. Hence I have reformatted them. Also, to typeset units, you better use `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
  \begin{aligned}
     A_{11} &= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SF_{11_{i}}}{Ext}}{\epsilon_{11}}\\
            &= \frac{66114.06667654557}{0.0005242901}\\
            &= \SI{126102075.631}{Nm}
  \end{aligned} &\quad &
  \begin{aligned}
     D_{11}&= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SM_{1_{i}}}{Ext}}{\kappa_{11}} \\
           &= \frac{0.106}{0.0002} \\
           &= \SI{373.068}{Nm}
  \end{aligned}\\[2ex]
%
  \begin{aligned}
    A_{12}&= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SF_{12_{i}}}{Ext}}{\epsilon_{12}}\\
          &= \frac{6295.129}{0.00011} \\
          &= \SI{56957543.627}{Nm}
  \end{aligned} &\quad &
  \begin{aligned}
    D_{12}&= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SM_{2_{i}}}{Ext}}{\kappa_{11}} \\
          &= \frac{0.355}{0.0002} \\
          &= \SI{1250.853}{Nm}
  \end{aligned}\\[2ex]
%
  \begin{aligned}
    A_{22}&= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SF_{22_{i}}}{Ext}}{\epsilon_{11}} \\
          &= \frac{36114775.225}{0.336} \\
          &= \SI{107378189.106}{Nm}
  \end{aligned}&\quad &
  \begin{aligned}
    D_{22}&= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SM_{2_{i}}}{Ext}}{\kappa_{22}} \\
          &= \frac{0.733}{0.304} \\
          &= \SI{2.404}{Nm}
  \end{aligned}\\[2ex]
%
  \begin{aligned}
     A_{66}&= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SF_{33_{i}}}{Ext}}{\epsilon_{12}} \\
           &= \frac{7836440.625}{0.279} \\
           &= \SI{28004682.576}{Nm}
  \end{aligned}&\quad &
  \begin{aligned}
    D_{66}&= \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SM_{3_{i}}}{Ext}}{\kappa_{12}} \\
          &= \frac{0.389}{0.571} \\
          &= \SI{1.22}{Nm}
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Like one of these?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

{\footnotesize
\begin{flalign*}
A11 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SF_{11_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{11}} = \frac{\num{66114.06667654557}}{\num{0.0005242901}} = \SI{126102075.631} {\N\m}
 & D11 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SM_{1_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{11}} = \frac{0.106}{0.0002} = \SI{373.068}{\N\m} \\[1ex]
A12 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SF_{12_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{12}} = \frac{\num{6295.129}}{\num{0.00011}} = \SI{56957543.627}{\N\m}
 & D12 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SM_{2_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{11}} = \frac{0.355}{\num{0.0002}} = \SI{1250.853}{\N\m} \\[1ex]
 A22 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SF_{22_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{11}} = \frac{\num{36114775.225}}{0.336} = \SI{107378189.106}{\N\m}
 & D22 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SM_{2_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{22}} = \frac{0.733}{0.304} = \SI{2.404}{\N\m} \\[1ex]
A66 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SF_{33_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{12}} = \frac{\num{7836440.625}}{0.279} = \SI{28004682.576}{\N\m}
 & D66 & = \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sum SM_{3_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{12}} = \frac{0.389}{0.571} = \SI{1.22}{\N\m}
\end{flalign*}}

\begin{align*}
A11 & \!\begin{aligned}[t] & = \dfrac{ \mfrac{\sum SF_{11_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{11}} = \mfrac{\num{66114.06667654557}}{\num{0.0005242901}}\\ & = \SI{126102075.631} {\N\m}\end{aligned}
 & D11 &\!\begin{aligned}[t] & = \dfrac{ \mfrac{\sum SM_{1_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{11}} = \mfrac{0.106}{0.0002}\\& = \SI{373.068}{\N\m}\end{aligned} \\[1.5ex]
%
A12 & \!\begin{aligned}[t]& = \dfrac{ \mfrac{\sum SF_{12_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{12}} = \mfrac{\num{6295.129}}{\num{0.00011}}\\ & = \SI{56957543.627}{\N\m}\end{aligned}
 & D12 &\!\begin{aligned}[t] & = \dfrac{ \mfrac{\sum SM_{2_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{11}} = \mfrac{0.355}{\num{0.0002}}\\& = \SI{1250.853}{\N\m} \end{aligned}\\[1.5ex]
%
 A22 & \!\begin{aligned}[t] & = \dfrac{ \mfrac{\sum SF_{22_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{11}} = \mfrac{\num{36114775.225}}{0.336}\\& = \SI{107378189.106}{\N\m}\end{aligned}
 & D22 & \!\begin{aligned}[t] & = \dfrac{ \mfrac{\sum SM_{2_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{22}} = \mfrac{0.733}{0.304}\\& = \SI{2.404}{\N\m}\end{aligned} \\[1.5ex]
%
A66 & \!\begin{aligned}[t] & = \dfrac{ \mfrac{\sum SF_{33_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\epsilon_{12}} = \mfrac{\num{7836440.625}}{0.279}\\ & = \SI{28004682.576}{\N\m}\end{aligned}
 & D66 &\!\begin{aligned}[t] & = \dfrac{ \mfrac{\sum SM_{3_{i}}}{\mathrm{Ext}}}{\kappa_{12}} = \mfrac{0.389}{0.571}\\ & = \SI{1.22}{\N\m}\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had forgotten the `[t]`option to `aligned`… Thanks for pointing it. Corrected now.

Comment: @Bernard thank you so much , but I get the error file not found , is it because of the \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath} ?

Comment: I use the package : \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  and \usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm]{geometry} , if I should change , how should I do that ?

Comment: dear please check my edited post , that I put the presets there

Comment: I can not mention

Comment: You may want to replace all unicode math symbols, e.g., `∑`, with their TeX-macro equivalents, e.g., `\sum`.

Comment: @Farzad64: The problem comes certainly from `mathtools` and/or `nccmath` that are not installed on your system. I suspect your distribution is  `MiKTeX` with a `basic` installation. If that is indeed the case, launch `MiKTeX Package Manager`, in administrator mode and select these two packages for installation. `Mathtools` extends and loads `amsmath`, so you don't have to load the latter if you load  mathtools.

Comment: @Mico: Once more I forgot my editor displays some kind of ‘pretty-printing’, and I find it so natural that I didn't notice it… It's corrected now.

Comment: Dear Bernard , I am using Texmaker , MikteX is another one ? well , when Installing , I remember I selected full installation

Comment: No: TeXmaker is just a specialised editor, not a distribution. The two main distributions are `MiKTeX` (only for Windows) and `TeX Live` (all platforms), plus `MacTeX`(for… MacOS, but it's based on TeXLive). Check with your package manager (MPM or tlmgr) if `mathtools `is installed. Ther has been some problems with mathtools last summer, because it was split into two packages, with different maintainers. But if you have a full installation, there should be no problems.